# How to make automatic tick on checkbox in Excel if the file is opened in Macro

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, combobox

I have the excel file with the comboboxes and tick boxes beside of them. What I need is to make automatic tick once I open the file.

The code of the ComboBox is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim filecsv As Variant 
filecsv = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.csv") 
If filecsv <> False Then 
Workbooks.Open Filename:=filecsv 
End If 
End Sub
```

Can you please help me on this? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use …

```
CheckBoxes("CheckBoxName").Value = True
```

where `CheckBoxName` is the name of your CheckBox.

Alternative solutions:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CheckBoxName").Object.Value = True
```

or

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("CheckBoxName").ControlFormat.Value = 1
```

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. • By the way *"Not working"* is not an error description.

Comment: The error I get is thi : Method 'Checkboxes' of Object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan See my edit. Depending on the type of the checkbox one of these must work.

Comment: I put the lines you mentioned before the END IF and I got the error like this :
'**Run-Time error '9'
Subscript out of range**'

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan That error means that either the worksheet name is wrong or that the CheckBox name is wrong (or does not exist). Only one of these solutions is working, depends on if you used a Form Control or an ActiveX Control.

Comment: Actually the sheet name is Sheet1, the checkbox name is CheckBox1. and it is activex Control. But still getting the same message :(

Comment: If it is an ActiveX and not a Form Control you must use `Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True` If this does not work you either have not an ActiveX Control or the sheet name is wrong or the CheckBox name is wrong. Check it again please.

Comment: I am really struggling with this. the code in my vba window is exactly like this : 


`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim filecsv As Variant
filecsv = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.csv")
If filecsv <> False Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:=filecsv
Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True
End If
End Sub`


Deleted the ActiveX Control and added again just in case, and checked the name. so Eveything is exactly what you say but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Try to specify the workbook: `ThisWorkbok.Worksheets("Sheet1")…`

Comment: I tried this : `ThisWorkbok.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True
`

now I am getting the error : Run time error 424 . Object required.

Comment: I mistyped `ThisWorkbook` sorry my bad. Of course there are two `o` in the word `Workbook`.

Comment: God finally :) Thanks a lot. Have a great day.